# .NET 8 MAUI get a result from a SQL query with SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, maui, .net-8.0

In my .NET 8 MAUI application, I have a SQLite database. I want to query this database and receive the result and transform the result in an object.

The query I want to run is

```
SELECT 
    ifnull(ws.cnt, 0) AS Impression, 
    ifnull(ws.cntRight, 0) AS Rights, 
    DictionaryId, Language, OriginalWord, 
    TranslateWords, WordType 
FROM 
    Words w 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         WordId, COUNT(*) AS cnt, 
         SUM(RightAnswer) AS cntRight 
     FROM 
         WordStatistic 
     GROUP BY 
         WordId) AS ws ON w.ID = ws.WordId
WHERE 
    DictionaryId = 1
ORDER BY 
    Impression, Rights
```

I would like to get as a result an object like this:

```
public class WordStat
{
    public int Impression { get; set; }
    public int Rights { get; set; }
    public long DictionaryId { get; set; }
    public int Language { get; set; }
    public string OriginalWord { get; set; }
    public string TranslateWords { get; set; }
    public int WordType { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to use my old code

```
public T ExecuteSQLScalar<T>(string sql)
{
    return database.ExecuteScalar<T>(sql);
}
```

but apparently this function is not exists anymore and I can use `ExecuteScalarAsync`. So, I tried

```
var qry = Database.ExecuteScalarAsync<WordStat>(strSQL);
```

but I get this error

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Don't know how to read LanguageInUse.Models.WordStat'

[image]

How can I execute a SQL query to the SQLite and get the result in the object I want?

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/database-sqlite?view=net-maui-8.0#advanced-configuration)?  To start with, any scalar method returns a single value, not a result set.  You probably want to use QueryAsync instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you can check official document [.NET MAUI local databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/database-sqlite?view=net-maui-8.0) ,just as Jason mendtioned.

And you can check the official sample here: [Local Database with SQLite](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/8.0/Data/TodoSQLite).

For your needs, you can try the following code.

```
  Database.QueryAsync<Item>(" ");
```

Just like the sample does, it is recommended that you create a new class of its own to operate on the database.

You can refer to the following code:

```
public class TodoItemDatabase
{
    SQLiteAsyncConnection Database;
    public TodoItemDatabase()
    {
    }
    async Task Init()
    {
        if (Database is not null)
            return;

        Database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.DatabasePath, Constants.Flags);
        var result = await Database.CreateTableAsync<TodoItem>();
    }

    public async Task<List<TodoItem>> GetItemsAsync()
    {
        await Init();
        return await Database.Table<TodoItem>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<List<TodoItem>> GetItemsNotDoneAsync()
    {
        await Init();
        return await Database.Table<TodoItem>().Where(t => t.Done).ToListAsync();
        
        // SQL queries are also possible
        //return await Database.QueryAsync<TodoItem>("SELECT * FROM [TodoItem] WHERE [Done] = 0");
    }

    public async Task<TodoItem> GetItemAsync(int id)
    {
        await Init();
        return await Database.Table<TodoItem>().Where(i => i.ID == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public async Task<int> SaveItemAsync(TodoItem item)
    {
        await Init();
        if (item.ID != 0)
        {
            return await Database.UpdateAsync(item);
        }
        else
        {
            return await Database.InsertAsync(item);
        }
    }

    public async Task<int> DeleteItemAsync(TodoItem item)
    {
        await Init();
        return await Database.DeleteAsync(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are totally right. I use `QueryAsync` in another part of the code. I don't know how I missed it! Thank you so much for your answer.